# Flutter WebView only gets content the first time

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I have a `WebView` where I parse the Site-content after the user presses a `Button`. If loading the site for the first time (`initUrl`), I get all the correct data. However if changing the sites within the browser, the site content is not loaded correctly. It feels like it only loads the first site correctly.

For example:

This is my initial Url:

> 'https://www.saturn.de/de/product/_apple-airpods-pro-in-ear-kopfhorer-bluetooth-weiss-2771284.html'

I parse it and I get all the correct images. However if going to another site and then back, I get other data. Why is this happening? I am lost here... What am I missing?

This is my `WebView`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Web View Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl:
                    'https://www.saturn.de/de/product/_apple-airpods-pro-in-ear-kopfhorer-bluetooth-weiss-2771284.html',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
                javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                  _extractDataJSChannel(context),
                },
                onPageStarted: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true;
                  });
                },
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    _imagesWithSize = [];

                    _currentUrl = url;
                    _isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goBack();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RoundedCornersTextButton(
                    title: 'GET',
                    isEnabled: !_isLoading,
                    onTap: () async {
                      await _getData();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goForward();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RoundedCornersTextButton(
              title: 'Google',
              isEnabled: !_isLoading,
              onTap: () async {
                await _controller.loadUrl('https://www.google.com');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _extractDataJSChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Flutter',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        String pageBody = message.message;
      },
    );
  }
```

As you can see I tried something with `JavaScript` but I can't get it to work.. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is "I parse it"? you parse the html and extract some data structure? or you just mean open the url

Comment: please use the debug mode of WebView, and look at (or paste the logs here). for example, it can be a bug of the website itself

Answer (score 0):

Try using `webview_flutter: ^3.0.2` in `pubspec.yaml` file.
I have modified your code and it's working fine.

```
            final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
        Completer<WebViewController>();
      
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Flutter Web View Example'),
            ),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: WebView(
                      initialUrl:
                      'https://www.saturn.de/de/product/_apple-airpods-pro-in-ear-kopfhorer-bluetooth-weiss-2771284.html',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                        _controller.complete(webViewController);
                      },
                      javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                        _extractDataJSChannel(context),
                      },
                      onPageStarted: (String url) {
      
                      },
                      onPageFinished: (String url) {
      
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
                          future: _controller.future,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                            return  IconButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await controller.data!.goBack();
                              },
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_back,
                                size: 50,
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
      
                      Flexible(
                        child: TextButton(
                          child: Text("get"),
      
                          onPressed: () async {
      
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
                          future: _controller.future,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                            return  IconButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await controller.data!.goForward();
                              },
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                size: 50,
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
                      future: _controller.future,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                        return FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                           await  controller.data!.loadUrl('https://www.google.com');
                          },
                          child: Text("Google"),
                        );
                      }),
      
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      
        JavascriptChannel _extractDataJSChannel(BuildContext context) {
          return JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'Flutter',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              String pageBody = message.message;
            },
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `flutter_inappwebview` to your `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
```

And add handler method in JavaScript side:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JavaScript Handler</h1>
    <button id='handleTest' onclick="window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('<yourJavaScriptMethod>');">Test</button>
</body>
```

Then use the `InAppWebView` instead of the `WebView` as below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Web View Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Web View Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
          child: InAppWebView(
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                    useHybridComposition: true
                )
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              _controller = controller
                ..addJavaScriptHandler(
                    handlerName: "<yourJavaScriptMethod>",
                    callback: (args) {
                      // handle
                      String pageBody = message.message;
                    });
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri url) {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = true;
              });
            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri url) {
              setState(() {
                _imagesWithSize = [];
                _currentUrl = url;
                _isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goBack();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RoundedCornersTextButton(
                    title: 'GET',
                    isEnabled: !_isLoading,
                    onTap: () async {
                      await _getData();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goForward();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RoundedCornersTextButton(
              title: 'Google',
              isEnabled: !_isLoading,
              onTap: () async {
                await _controller.loadUrl('https://www.google.com');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```